# My media query in SCSS in not working properly

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

here is my code:

```
.showcase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 93vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vXqDmnh/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 120px 100px 250px black, inset -120px -100px 250px black;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .showcase {
    height: 70vh;
  }
  .hide-sm {
    display: none;
  }
  .showcase-top img {
    top: 30%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(0);
  }

  .showcase-content {
    h1 {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
      line-height: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here only (.hide-sm) class is working but other classes are not working. I tried to see using chrome dev tools but it shows that the original styling is not changed. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: Silly question maybe but have you made your window less than 960px wide?

Comment: yes i have tried making it bigger or smaller. only one class(.hide-sm) works others doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance you could show a screenshot from your browser's CSS inspector for the `.showcase` element (you can copy / paste screenshot directly into the question editor)? The only property that should be overridden is `height` (`93vh` standard, overridden by `70vh`) so if you could show that, it would help.

Comment: Also, are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: i closed everything and run the sass script again and it started working. Thank you for your help!